# How to replace multiple characters from text?

Tags: javascript

As you can see in my code I am trying to replace some characters! So I want this:
First I remove all "||", 
Then I remove all two or more white spaces with one space,
Then I replace all one space with "-"

With my code all two or more spaces are replacing with single space and all single spaces getting replace with "-". But the problem is this "|" is not getting removed. Please help!!

```
document.getElementById("NormalText").value.replace(/|/g, '').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(/ /g, '-');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe symbol like so.

```
value.replace(/\|/g, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example isn't working because the pipe character has special meaning in regex; it is used for [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). For example, `a|c` replaces all instances of `a` and `c`:

```js
const myString = "abc";
const result = myString.replace(/a|c/g,"");
console.log(result);
```

To match a literal `|` character, escape it with a preceding backslash: `\|`:

```js
const myString = "my|string";
const result = myString.replace(/\|/g, '');
console.log(result);
```